# How can I get specific object from methods response JSON

Tags: java, android

I want to call another method if the condition is satisfied with the response of first method. But the response is in JSON and has many objects. I want to check if "RESPCODE" is "01" and if it is call a method.

*Method:*

```
@Override
public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction is successful " + inResponse);

    if(inResponse.toString().equals("01")) {
        CheckoutProcess();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Transaction Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction : " + inResponse);

    }
}
```

*Response:*

```
TXNAMOUNT = 1000.00
PAYMENTMODE = PPI
CURRENCY = INR 
TXNDATE = 2018-04-17 18:56:08.0
STATUS = TXN_SUCCESS
RESPCODE = 01
RESPMSG = Txn Success
GATEWAYNAME = WALLET
BANKTXNID = 
BANKNAME = WALLET
```

Comment: could you add your JSON response.

Comment: I have added, check response

Comment: reference https://www.javatpoint.com/java-json-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: That response is not JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.json library should be enough if it is only one or two properties you are interested in.

Use org.json library to parse it and create JsonObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(<jsonStr>);
```

Now, use this object to get your values:

```
int respcode = jsonObj.getInt("RESPCODE");
```

You can see a complete example here:

[How to parse JSON in Java](http://codedestine.com/how-read-write-json-in-java)